# How can I get the latest compatible app version?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.1-eclair, compatibility, lg-gt540-optimus

I once had Acrobat Reader and Seesmic installed in my LG GT540 (Android 2.1).

I had to uninstall them to free some space. After a few days I tried to install those apps again, but their updates made them unavailable to my Android version.

Is there anything I could do to install the latest compatible version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not exactly what I was looking for, but it works... it is more like a *preventive approach*.

So, my solution would was to install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (which requires root access to work) and backup all my apps. Then, whenever I need more space, I just backup my apps before I go on. If I need them again, I can use Titanium Backup and restore.

And this is why I consider it a preventive approach: it is all about regular backups.

If anyone knows a better way to do this, please share =)